# How many recursive function calls does a binary search make?

Tags: recursion, binary-search

A binary search is O(log2 N). Does this mean that the depth of the activation records stack would be log2 N? In other words, how many recursive function calls are made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the recursion depth is **O**(log N).  You need to keep making calls until you reach your base case, which is individual elements.  However, the exact quantity of calls is dependent on the algorithm: some stop at the atom level, some one call deeper when the passed list is 0.  It depends on the list length, but the exact count depends on the implementation.